# Using a javascript string variable like a DOM object

Tags: javascript, dom

i want to know if i can use a string variable in javascript, like this:

```
var str = 
  '<html>
   <head>
     <title>Status page</title>
   </head>
   <body style="font-family: sans-serif;">
     <p style="font-size: 1.2em;font-weight: bold;margin: 1em 0px;">Forbidden</p>
     <p>Attempting to finish {Interaction5e8d4072-6b49-4e69-b084-1d8e741f4f10.habla}, an interaction without cleaned dependencies</p>
     <p>You can get technical details <a href="http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4">here</a>.<br>
       Please continue your visit at our
       <a href="/">home page</a>.
     </p>
   </body>
   </html>';
```

like a DOM object and how.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the JS functions such as 'createElement' and 'appendChild'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, should you if the real question.

```
var str = '<p>Some paragraph</p>';

document.write(str); // Or
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML(str);
```